# Why are these numbers above the line?

Tags: mathematics, pattern

The numbers above the line and below the line have a specific property to them:

\begin{array}{c}
       1\ 3\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 9\ 10\ 11\ 12\ 13\ \ldots \\
\hline 2\ 4\ 8\ 15\ 16\ 21\ 30\ 32\ 33\ \ldots & 
\end{array}

Every natural number has a place either above or below the line.

What is this property? What are the next three numbers on each line? Would the numbers 29, 52, and 138 go above or below the line?

Comment: No hits on [OEIS](http://oeis.org). Once solved, if the property is of mathematical interest, it may be worth submitting.

Comment: @nneonneo Are you sure? [I get three results.](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13&go=Search)

Comment: The property is indeed a mathematical one, although I didn't think to check OEIS for it.

Comment: @Doorknob: the bottom sequence returns no hits. And none of the top three results describes my pattern.

Comment: Whoops, just noticed that they all also contain either 15 or 16, making them invalid.

Comment: Are the numbers shown in order? That is, can we assume that every natural number less than 33 not shown on the bottom belongs on the top?

Comment: Yes, the numbers are shown in order.

Comment: So you get for free that the next three numbers on the top of the line are 14, 17, and 18, and that 29 would appear above the line, but the rest is the hard part.

Comment: I don't know if this is coincidence or not, but it appears that all (odd) primes are above the line, while (positive) powers of $2$ are below.

Comment: Nope, that's not a coincidence. That's a hint to the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers are below the line exactly if their number of distinct odd prime factors is even, except $1$ goes above the line. Equivalently, numbers are below the line when the sum of their distinct prime factors is even and positive.

So, $29$ would go above the line (odd prime), $52 = 2^2 \times 13$ would go above, and  $138 = 2 \times 3 \times 23$ would go below.

Comment: What about 2, 4, 8, and 16? They have no odd factors, but they are below the line.

Comment: @Kevin You're right, I was trying to make an exception for 1 and got it wrong. Fixing.

Comment: Isn't this something to do with the Mobius mu function?

Comment: You got it. The second one was what I was going for, and the exact formulation I had in mind was: "Numbers are above the line when the sum of their distinct prime factors is odd, with 1 counting as 1 by itself."